# d3.csv manipulate data switch column displayed

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

The data are read from a cvs.file

```
    "col1","col2"
    "row1col1","row1col2"
```

I would like to switch the column data in a force layout to select column 2 or column 1, but dynamically.

```
    node = nodeG.selectAll(".node")
            .data(data, function(d) {return d.column1;});//first option

    node = nodeG.selectAll(".node")
            .data(data, function(d) {return d.column2;});//second option
```

I tried to use a variable, for some reason it didn't work

```
    var data_variable = function(d) {return d.column1;}
                        || function(d) {return d.column2;} 
                        // pseudocode, data from input options

    node = nodeG.selectAll(".node")
            .data(data, data_variable);
```

Is this the correct approach or are the data better manipulated before display ?

Comment: The optional function you pass to `.data` is a [key](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) function.  It doesn't control what data is displayed but rather how joins are computed.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to fully understand: the key represents the position in a row in the column though, doesn't it ? I understand that I can map the column values to a new array and work with that. Changing the key does not return different values ?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data)? The key function doesn't change what's returned or map anything to anything else.

Comment: I do not find the concept that self evident. If the 'key function returns a string', example d.name,  should I not be be able to get a different string from a different key function d.other_name ?

Comment: http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.de/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html - if anyone might read this post - you will find a good explanation of the key function/identity function at the linked website. It does give you an idea as to why my intention can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up to be  a simple solution inside the main function:

```
var ls = d3.select("#selector").property("value");

if (ls === 'it' ){

  idValue = function(d) {
  return d.col1;
  };

  textValue = function(d) {
  return d.col1;
  };

 } else {

  idValue = function(d) {
  return d.col2;
  };

  textValue = function(d) {
  return d.col2;
  };

 };
```

I simply obtain the value from a drop down list and chose the returned functions conditionally